# jQuery mouseout animation firing only after 2nd hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

We are using the following to animate a div on hover and then animate back to its original state on mouseout.

Everything works fine, however the mouseout does not fire until we have hovered over the div a 2nd time. After that, it works perfectly.

```
$('#navigation-captions>li>a')
.hover(function(){
    if(!$(this).next().is(".open")) {
    $(this).next().css({'visibility' : 'visible'}).animate({opacity: 1}, 150).addClass('open')
    }else if ($(this).next().is(".open")) {
    $('#navigation-captions>li>a').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).next().stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 150, function(){$(this).next().css({'visibility' : 'hidden'})}).removeClass('open')
})}})
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So it's either visible when starting out, or the condition fails, meaning the next element has no "open" class, and is that an event handler inside an event handler, if so, that would cause strange issues, and so would not indenting the code properly.

Comment: You are binding `mouseout` inside your `hover` handler. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for your situation?

```
$('#navigation-captions>li>a').hover(function() {
    $(this).next().css({'visibility' : 'visible'}).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 150).addClass('open');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).next().stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 150, function(){
        $(this).next().css({'visibility' : 'hidden'}).removeClass('open')
    })
});
```

The event will always work the first time. Removing the if-block, makes the code cleaner and makes it less likely to get into an inconsistent state.

Also, it is recommended you use on() if your version of jQ supports it.

```
$('#navigation-captions>li>a').on('hover', function() {
    $(this).next().css({'visibility' : 'visible'}).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 150).addClass('open');
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).next().stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 150, function(){
        $(this).next().css({'visibility' : 'hidden'}).removeClass('open')
    })
});
```